# How to multithread core-schedule onto different cores (ideally in C++)

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, pthreads

I have a large C++11 multithreaded application where the threads are always active, communicating to each other constantly, and should be scheduled on different physical CPUs for reasonable performance.

The default Linux behavior AFAIK is that threads will typically/often get scheduled onto the same CPU, causing horrible performance.

To solve this, I understand how to attach threads to specific physical CPUs in C++, e.g.:

```
    std::cout << "Assign to thread cpu " << cpu << "\n";
    cpu_set_t cpuset;
    CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
    CPU_SET(cpu, &cpuset);
    int rc = pthread_setaffinity_np(thread.native_handle(), sizeof(cpu_set_t), &cpuset);
```

and can use this to pin to specific CPUs, e.g. attach 4 threads to CPUs 0,2,4,6.

However this approach requires a specific CPU number which is a problem in that there may be many programs running on a host using other CPUs. These might be my program or other programs. As just one example an 8 core machine might have two copies of my 4-threaded application so obviously having both of those two programs pick the same 4 CPUs is a problem.

I'd thus like a way to say "schedule the threads in this set all on different CPUs without caring of the CPU number".  Is this possible in C++(11)?

If not, is this possible with numactl or another utility?   E.g. I don't want "numactl -C 0,2,4,6" but rather "numactl -C W,X,Y,Z" where the scheduler can pick arbitrary W,X,Y,Z subject to W!=X!=Y!=Z.

I'm most interested in Linux behavior.  I cannot change the OS configuration.  I don't want the separate applications to cross communicate (nor can they as they might be other applications I do not control.)

Once I have the answer to this, the follow up is how do I modify this to add a e.g. fifth thread I do want to schedule on the same CPU as the first thread?

Comment: This kind of sounds like your real problem is that your threads are all busy-waiting rather than blocking when they don't have something useful to do yet.  If so, the proper fix to get good performance would be to make sure the threads only use CPU cycles when they have useful work to do, and then block when their current work is done so that some other thread can use the CPU resources.  That is the behavior the Linux scheduler expects and is optimized for.

Comment: The program is extremely well scheduled, with the threads with proper CPU scheduling 99% doing real work, so the problem is as stated.

Answer (score 0):

My problem in a specific Boost ASIO multithreaded application is, that even with a limited number of threads (like ten) on a system with much more cores, the threads get pushed around onto different cores all the time, which seriously reduces performances due to a high number of L1/L2 cache misses.

I have not searched much, yet, but there is a `getcpu()` system call on Linux, that returns the CPU-ID and NUMA Node-ID of the active thread, that is calling getcpu(). To get a set of unique CPU-IDs, one could try to create all threads, first, then let them all wait for a barrier via `pthread_barrier_wait()` and after that call `getcpu()` repeatedly in each thread until the returned values have stabilized. Stability has been reached, when each thread has gotten the same CPU-ID as answer for at least the last 1000 calls to `getcpu()` AND all the answers to all the different threads are different. It is of extreme importance to use non-blocking techniques like `std::atomic` values to synchronize during this testing phase. Because, if you wait for some Mutexes instead, the likelyhood is high, that your threads get re-mixed again by the scheduler.

After stability has been reached, each thread just sets its CPU affinity to its current CPU-ID and you are done.

In many cases, where you do not dynamically start and stop a lot of applications, hand-binding the threads to certain Cores might be the easiest solution, though. And if you do start and stop a lot of apps dynamically, the "pick N free cores" algo described above will fail miserably, if there aren't enough free cores left, anyways.